# Framer motion nextjs useScroll not working when attached to an element

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I tried to implement scrolling animation as such to a component:

```js
"use client";

import { useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import { motion, useScroll } from "framer-motion";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./index.module.scss";

const SelectedWork = ({ title, description, year, image }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["start end", "end end"],
  });

  const imageSrc = useMemo(
    () => image.src.split("/")[image.src.split("/").length - 1].split(".")[0],
    [image]
  );

  return (
    <motion.div
      className={styles.works__wrapper}
      id={imageSrc}
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        opacity: scrollYProgress,
        scale: scrollYProgress,
      }}
    >
      <div className={styles.image__container__wrapper}>
        <motion.div className={styles.image__container}>
          <div className={styles.image__overlay}>
            <p>See More</p>
          </div>
          <Image
            src={image}
            alt={title}
            sizes="100vw"
            objectFit="contain"
            className={styles.image}
          />
        </motion.div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.work__details}>
        <div>
          <h5 className={styles.title}>{title}</h5>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.description}>
          <h6>{description}</h6>
        </div>
        <h6>{year}</h6>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default SelectedWork;
```

The idea is to scale the whole `div` and also the opacity when I scroll through the page and when I first encounter the component on the page. But somehow right now, `scrollYProgress` is basically just `0`, which means that the `div` is currently just gone. What am I missing here though?

Note that this is a separate component which I later import into `Page.jsx`

Answer (score 2):

Framer motion variables are updated out of the render cycle of ReactJS/NextJS. Which essentially means that scrollYProgress is updated but your component is not which is the reason why you are not able to see the opacity changing even though you are scrolling through the component.

A fix would be to explicitly subscribe to the scroll updates using useMotionValueEvent from framer-motion as shown below.

```
  const [hookedYPostion, setHookedYPosition] = useState(0);
  useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, "change", (latest) => {
    setHookedYPosition(latest);
  })
```

You can use the state and bind it in your styles, and then your component would re render when framer motion updates the scrollYProgress just the way you want it to.

Now, I understand that it might not be the best approach as it can lead to frequent component re render which in some case might lead to blocking the main UI thread.
Another approach could be to use the [`useTransform`](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-transform/) hook from framer motion like below.

```
  const scaleOpacityProgress = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0,1], [0,1]);
```

and now you can bind this variable to any motion component style and it would update without causing re-renders.

**NOTE: there will be no console logs if you try to log as the updates from useTransform are also not a part of React's component render cycle**

I hope it helps!